# Appcelerator iOS sudden crash

Tags: ios, firebase, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

The following warning message shows up on my console when I try to save data on Firebase and the list where the data is located refreshes. Most of the time this happens when I save an image or video url in Firebase and then an imageview calls the url, and after this the app crashes.

This is the warning message:

> [WARN] :   1   0x100401320 std::__1::__tree, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::less, std::__1::allocator > >, std::__1::allocator, std::__1::allocator > > >::destroy(std::__1::__tree_node, std::__1::allocator >, void*>*)
>   [WARN] :   2   0x100452208 std::__1::__tree, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::less, std::__1::allocator > >, std::__1::allocator, std::__1::allocator > > >::destroy(std::__1::__tree_node, std::__1::allocator >, void*>*)

As a reference I am using:
 - Titanium SDK 5.1.2.GA.
 - Amazon S3.
 - Module com.leftlanelab.firebase 1.1.1

The data lives in a listview that contains images and text.

This is my code on js

```
function evalMedia(str) {
    var TEMPLATE_TEXT = "messageTemplate";
    var TEMPLATE_PHOTO = "imageTemplate";
    var TEMPLATE_VIDEO = "videoTemplate";
    var PHOTO = "/images/";
    var VIDEO = "/videos/";
    return (str.indexOf(PHOTO) != -1) ? ((str.indexOf(VIDEO) != -1) ? TEMPLATE_VIDEO : TEMPLATE_PHOTO) : TEMPLATE_TEXT;
}

function showDataUpdates(data) {
    var updates = [];
    for (i in data) {
        updates.push({
            message : {
                value : data[i].message,
                time : data[i].timestamp
            },
            msg : {
                value : data[i].message,
                key : i
            },
            mov : {
                key : i,
            },
            image : {
                image : data[i].message,
                key : i
            },
            video : {
                url : data[i].message
            },
            sender : {
                text : data[i].sender
            },
            time : {
                text : format(data[i].timestamp)
            },
            template : evalMedia(data[i].message)
        });
    }
    sort = [];
    sort = updates.sort(function(a, b) {
        return parseFloat(a.message.time) - parseFloat(b.message.time);
    });
    $.loading.hide();
    var items = [];
    for(var k = 0; k < messages; k++){
        if(sort[k])
            items.push(sort[k]);
    }
    $.listMessages.sections[0].setItems(items);
    updates = null;
}

var listMessages = Firebase.new('updates/' + args.item.post.id);
listMessages.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var _updates = snapshot.val();
    if (evalObject(_updates)) {
        showDataUpdates(_updates);
    }else{
        $.loading.hide();
    }
});
```

Is there a problem with the imageview calling the url or is it something else?

Comment: Do you have an example of such an image URL?

Comment: image URL: https://livepostrocks.s3.amazonaws.com/images/-KFQu6gTjOOkxgmLuXTT_1460759077673.jpg

Comment: You probably tried this yourself already, but that image itself works fine. Could you turn the above code snippet in something we can test to reproduce and fix? Then please create a [JIRA ticket](https://jira.appcelerator.org/), link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Fokke, I have added the ticket to JIRA. TIcket AC-3522

Comment: Is this module working with Titanium SDK 5.5.0 ? ( The Firebase module )

Comment: i actually have this version <sdk-version>5.2.2.GA</sdk-version> and its fine. @JuanCarlosSalinasOjeda

Comment: Can you please show me the link to download it ? .. thanks !! i want to use Firebase but i did not how to do it with Titanium.

Comment: You can checkout it here : https://github.com/LeftLaneLab/firebase-titanium , i still use firebase with titanium only in IOS, in Android case i'm using it whit the Android sdk  https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup